# Cannot load some websites using my wifi

Tags: internet

Linux noob needs some help pls.

I just installed Ubuntu 16.

Some websites (I'd say around half) cannot be loaded when I use wifi from my router, but everything is completely fine if I use my cellphone as a hotspot and connect my laptop to it.

It returns network unreachable when I try to ping anything except 127.0.0.1.
Any other device using the router works completely fine. Using a cable instead of the wifi on the router also allows it to work completely fine.

```
ping network.com
```

gets

```
connect: network unreachable
```

Comment: Open a terminal and try $ ping website.com and check the output. (Replace website.com with the websites that dont work obviously) If you get `ping: unknown host website.com` then you have a DNS problem, and you should set e.g. `8.8.8.8` as the DNS server in your network settings. If you get something else, comment it on my response or so.

Comment: ping website.com gets me  connect: network unreachable